# Use apn and gcm on react-native

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, react-native, apple-push-notifications

**How to use APN and GCM on react-native?**

Is there any plugin like `phonegap-plugin-push` on Apache Cordova?

Comment: Have you looked? In a quick google search I found: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

Comment: @rmevans9 thank you!